# JSON.stringify is ignoring object properties

Tags: javascript, json, kendo-ui, stringify

See the jsfiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/frigon/H6ssq/

For some reason there are fields that JSON.stringify is ignoring.  Is there a way to force JSON.stringify to parse them?

As the jsfiddle shows... this code...

```
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2012.2.710/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    var model = kendo.data.Model.define({id: "ID", fields: {"Name":{type: "string"}}});
    var obj = new model();
    obj.set("Name","Johhny Foosball");
    document.write("<br />obj.dirty property exists: ");
    document.write(obj.dirty);
    document.write("<br/>obj.uid property exists: ");
    document.write(obj.uid);
    document.write("<br/>But they dont show in JSON.stringify():<br/>");    
    document.write(JSON.stringify(obj));
</script>
```

will output:

obj.dirty property exists: true

obj.uid property exists: b4af4dfc-9d94-4a2d-b286-d6f4cbc991d8

But they dont show in JSON.stringify():

{"ID":"","Name":"Johhny Foosball"}

Answer (score 34, accepted):

When an object has its own `toJSON()` implementation, `JSON.stringify()` uses the object returned from that method and stringifies that. `kendo.data.Model` defines it's own `toJSON()` method which only returns the properties defined on the model, which is why you aren't seeing other values (e.g. `dirty`, `id`, `uid`) in the string result.

"*If the stringify method sees an object that contains a toJSON method, it calls that method, and stringifies the value returned. This allows an object to determine its own JSON representation.*"

Here's an alternative if you *must* have all properties on the object:

```
var model = kendo.data.Model.define({
    id: "ID",
    fields: {
        "Name": { type: "string" }
    }
});
var obj = new model();
obj.set("Name","Johhny Foosball");    
var newObj = $.extend({}, obj);
delete newObj.toJSON;
document.write(newObj.dirty);
document.write(JSON.stringify(newObj));
```

..and the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H6ssq/6/).

Basically I used `jQuery.extend` to clone the object then deleted the `toJSON` function. Use at your own risk! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're working in NodeJS you can use:

```
import * as util from 'util';
util.inspect(obj)
```

instead of JSON.stringify

Answer (score 0):

It is using its own JSON.stringify method. This has happened to me with Sequelize. I stringify the object before adding the new property like this:

```
objStringified = JSON.stringify(obj) // uses its own JSON.stringify method
obj = JSON.parse(objStringified) // only shows properties specified as columns in its model
obj.dirty = "whatever";
finalObj = JSON.stringify(objParsed); // now it doesn't have its own JSON.stringify method, so dirty property appears
```

Answer (score -5):

Somewhat relevant, as I came here looking for a solution to a similar situation: For those looking for a way to get back their original object, before kendo added all sorts of weird hidden properties to it, do:

```
cleanObject = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(kendoDataItem));
```

I encountered this scenario when I needed to pass the selected item from the kendo tree to a json-formatter directive. But what do you know, kendo had allready messed up with my original object.

```
<div kendo-tree-view="tree" k-data-source="treeData" k-on-change="selectedItem=dataItem">
    {{dataItem.text}}
</div>

<json-formatter open="1" json="selectedItem"></json-formatter>
```

Comment: Seriously? The guy says that `JSON.stringify` is not working and you use `JSON.stringify` in your example?

Comment: Read carefully.

Comment: JSON.stringify is not working. How would that code return the correct values?