# JSON Object not fully converts to String?

Tags: javascript, json, stringify

I am facing an issue that JSON.stringify not stringifies all the keys in a JSON Object.

ie. `window.performance.getEntries()[0]` contains around 17 keys. But on converting to a string, the result contains only 4 keys.

How can I convert all the keys in `window.performance.getEntries()[0]`?

I want the complete string output of `window.performance.getEntries()` which is an array and I used `JSON.stringify(window.performance.getEntries())`.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: sample for `window.performance.getEntries()[0]`

Comment: Sorry, but without an example or screenshot, we cannot help you...

Comment: Works for me `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(window.performance.getEntries())).length == window.performance.getEntries().length == true` have you examined the entry at which parsing stops?

Comment: @AlexK. — `window.performance.getEntries()` != `window.performance.getEntries()[0]` The question is asking about the properties of the objects in the array that returns, not the entries in the array itself.

Comment: Aye but *I want the complete string output of window.performance.getEntries()*

Comment: @AlexK. — Which would include **all** of the properties of all the objects it contains, not just **some** of the properties for all of the objects.

Comment: That is very interesting that it is only including only four. For the lazy, run it in your Chrome console...

Comment: For sample Just paste window.performance.getEntries() or Just performance.getEntries() in browser console.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON.stringify is ignoring object properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20511421/json-stringify-is-ignoring-object-properties)

Answer (score 1):

window.performance seems to have is own `toJSON`-function and so can determine what will be stringified. Here is a answer and a work around to your question from a similiar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20511811/3400898

> "If the stringify method sees an object that contains a toJSON method, it calls that method, and stringifies the value returned. This allows an object to determine its own JSON representation."

Answer (score 0):

As other stated it is because there is a toJSON method defined. Basically you need to loop over every index of the array and than every property in the object.

```
var adjusted = window.performance.getEntries().map( function (result) {       
    var temp = {}, key;
    for (key in result) if (key!=="toJSON") temp[key]=result[key]; 
    return temp;
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(adjusted[0]));
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplified solution for this problem which I found is

```
var jsonArray = $.map(performance.getEntries(),function(jsonObj){
    var obj = $.extend({},jsonObj);
    delete obj.toJSON;
    return obj;
});

JSON.stringify(jsonArray);
```